# WordPress gives 404 on uploaded pdf only on Safari

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, safari, http-status-code-404

If I link to an uploaded PDF WordPress gives a 404 error, but only on Safari. Chrome and Firefox are working fine.

https://www.frieslandlease.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Leaflet-Prive%CC%81-Leasefiets-Friesland-Lease.pdf

The server is running nginx so I can't use a .htacces file.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that safari is not able to handle special characters in the url

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me a ton of time.